# How do I initialize the `<base>` tag correctly

Tags: html

I want to add the `<base>` tag inside the html `<head>`. I already have a `config.inc.php` file, so might as well add it there, like so:

`config.inc.php`:

```
$config = [
    'home' => [
        'base' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
    ],


    'html' => [
        'lang' => 'es_ES',
        'charset' => 'utf-8'
    ]
];
```

and this is how i add it on the HTML `</head>`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php echo $config['html']['charset']; ?>">
    <base href="<?php echo $config['home']['base']; ?>">
</head>
```

The question is how do I initialize the `<base>` tag correctly on my `config.inc.php` file?

I do it like this:

```
'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
```

Is there a better way, or not... Do i need a slash (/) at the end?

Comment: Are you using a php framework?

Comment: @VictorC I'm not using a framework